# Oracle SQL unsigned integer

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In Oracle, what is the equivalent to MySQL's UNSIGNED?

I have the following query, only it doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Edit: My purpose is to save space, because for some fields I won't be using negative values. Alternatively, it would answer my question of someone confirms that what I'm asking for is impossible in Oracle 11g, or if it's possible, but not straightforward to do (more than 3 lines of code per unsigned int).

Also, It's not necessarily about *int*. I also use smallint and tinyint.

Comment: What do you actually want to happen - you want to prevent negative numbers being stored? Do you want a range of valid values? What do you want to happen if someone tried to insert a negative or out-of-range number?

Comment: If you are supremely worried about how many bytes your data is going to use, you probably don't want to use Oracle -- or any other current relational or non-relational DBMS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to match the restrictions shown [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html), you can use a check constraint:

```
SQL> create table foo (id number primary key, 
    constraint foo_uint_id check (id between 0 and 4294967295));

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo (id) values (-1);

insert into foo (id) values (-1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.FOO_UINT) violated

SQL> insert into foo (id) values (0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo (id) values (4294967295);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo (id) values (4294967296);

insert into foo (id) values (4294967296)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.FOO_UINT_ID) violated

SQL> select * from foo;

        ID
----------
         0
4294967295
```

Comment: I also want to take less space. Alternatively, it would satisfy me if someone confirms that my task cannot be done in a simple way.

Comment: Number storage might not work how you expect; see [this AskTom article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1856720300346322149). Using less space probably isn't a useful goal?

Answer (score 2):

Here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i54330 is the definitive list of Oracle's built in datatypes.

If you want the semantics of integers, then `number(n)` is basically your only option. Personally I use `integer` which is a slightly shorter way of saying `number(38)`.

Comment: So Oracle does not support unsigned integer numbers then?

Comment: Oracle does, by using the constraint approach outlined by Alex, but not as a native datatype.