# How to create a positive integer column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, constraints

Is it possible to create a positive integer in Oracle ?

I tried the following SQL but none of them is working :

```
ALTER TABLE testtable ADD TestColumn UNSIGNED;

ALTER TABLE testtable ADD TestColumn UNSIGNED Int;

ALTER TABLE testtable ADD TestColumn Int(Unsigned);
```

Thanks,
Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338044/oracle-sql-unsigned-integer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable ADD TestColumn Int CHECK(TestColumn > 0);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b332f1bb404f1ed24f89b6e2c1103e7a)**

Comment: Nice(+1), but "positive" is not equal to "non-negative". So, converted "TestColumn >= 0" to "TestColumn > 0"

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks, yes word possitive means exactly as you stated `>0` :) I used `>=` because `UNSIGNED` keyword in MySQL means "0 or greater than zero" [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=099b9cf9f8ee8414fdb1a1df642ce8e8)